# Android Send ArrayList Data to MySQL using Volley

Tags: php, android, mysqli, android-volley

I'm trying to send ArrayList data to MySQL by using PHP as a bridge, and to achieve same I've implemented code using Volley

Here is what I've written:

```
private void uploadToDatabase() {

    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {
        image_file = imageList.get(i).getImageFileName();
    }

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            response -> {
                try {
                    JSONArray itemArray = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("images");
                    for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
                        String value = itemArray.getString(i);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result:" + value + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }, error -> Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG)) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() {

            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put("image_file", image_file);

            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(UploadActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Neither I'm getting response nor Error, let's have a look at server side code:

db_config.php

```
<?php 

    $DB_HOST = "localhost";
    $DB_USER = "";
    $DB_PASS = "";
    $DB_NAME = "primary_db";

 $conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

 ?>
```

upload_data.php:

```
<?php 

    include "db_config.php";
    $conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASS,$DB_NAME);

    if($conn)
    {

        $json = $_POST['images'];
        $json_array = json_decode($json,true);

        for($i=0; $i<count($json_array);$i++)
        {
            $image_file = $json_array[$i]["image_file"];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO images(image_file) values('$image_file')";

            if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
            {
                echo json_encode(array('response'=>'uploaded successfully'));
            }

        }

    }

    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'connection Failed'));
    }

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Where I'm doing mistake, why I'm unable to post arraylist data to server using Volley

**UPDATE # 1**

This

```
    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {
        image_file = imageList.get(i).getImageFileName();
    }
```

Replaced with

```
    final String image_file = imageDataList.get(0).getImageFileName();
```

Comment: What is the type of the variable `image_file`?

Comment: String only @AtishAgrawal

Comment: According to your code, `image_file = imageList.get(i).getImageFileName();` this line will update the image_file with the last file name whichever is inside the list imageList. Do you think this is correct logic you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to upload all the available file names I have in the list... but main concern is none of the file name got uploaded to table

Comment: As per my understanding, you are doing it incorrectly. You need to create a JSON Array of all the filenames and then post it to the server. Also, I think, the imageList variable is already a List, you can convert it directly to JSON Array and pass it to the params.

Comment: can you share the code, you think I should use to send arraylist data to mysql, and one more thing, I made a small change as you can see above check UPDATE #1 @AtishAgrawal